# Position of a character NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have string which contains either A ,B, C, or D     (example  A123 or B235 or 2B35  but not AB123)

I want to find the index of A,B,C or D

In C # we write as

```
String s = "123B";    
index = s.IndexOfAny(new char[] = {A,B,C,D});
```

How to write in Objective-C??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`-rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfCharacterFromSet_):

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCD"];
NSRange range = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];

if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    // ... oops
} else {
    // range.location is the index
}
```