# Locating and removing an esc sequence objective-c

Tags: string, cocoa, replace

I'm trying to remove an escape sequence (\p) from selected strings (for reuse in other places in my code). I want to create a separate object that holds that cleaned up string. Like this

```
(pseudo code)
 NSString *stringWithEscSequence = anEdgewoodSecretPlace.placeName;
 NSString *stringWithoutEscSequence = [removeTheEscSequenceP stringWithEscSequence];

 (where removeTheEscSequenceP is what I'm trying to figure out how to do)
```

....

I played with NSString formats and I found  related questions at
     [Position of a character NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188156/position-of-a-character-nsstring)
and
     [how to replace one substring with another in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150066/how-to-replace-one-substring-with-another-in-objective-c)
I can break out the substring that follows the escape sequence use ideas from the second posting. So I thought then I should try to locate the actual index of the escape sequence. But I can't figure out how to do that. Also I think there is probably a less messy, more straightforward way to do this, that I'm not thinking of.

I was playing around with the first posting ideas, though I knew that I was in a kind of primitive mode. But as soon as I attempt to replace "ABCD" with "\". I get an error 'Missing terminating """ = except if I put the ABCD string back in I'm not missing any quotes. I think it's because of the special nature ofo the \ character.

Even if I could figure out how to search for the "\" and then a "p" following that, I don't think that's really the best way to approach this

```
 NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCD"];


    NSRange range2 = [testCleanString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];

    if (range2.location == NSNotFound) {
        NSLog (@"Didn't find esc sequence");

    } else {
        NSLog (@"range.location is %lu",(unsigned long)range2.location );

    }
```

Comment: could you explain why `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` does not work for you?

Comment: Can't explain it because that's probably what I need to learn how to use! I will look at that. Thank you.

Comment: NSString *newString = [testCleanString
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
      
      NSLog (@"newString is %@", newString);

Comment: The above worked and thanks to sergio, I know how to do something I didn't know before. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to flag this as answered, since sergio's answer was a comment. I can't find a checkmark to check and could only vote up his answer.

Comment: glad it helped! I have added an answer below, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

```
NSString* stringWithoutEscSequence = [stringWithEscSequence stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"stringToRemove" withString:@"replacement"];
```

If you want to replace multiple characters you could do:

```
NSCharacterSet* toRemove = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n\p\t"];
NSString* stringWithoutEscSequence = [[stringWithEscSequence componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:toRemove] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
```